# Ordinary Differential Equations - Sturm Liouville

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me on the following issue?

Show that between two consecutive zeros of any nontrivial real solution of $(p (x) u ')' + q (x) u = 0$ there is exactly one point of maximum or minimum point where $q (x)> 0$.

Comment: **Hint:** [Sturm separation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_separation_theorem)